# Все-таки "ветра" или "ветры"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

По идее, правильно говорить "ветры" (насколько я помню), но в стихах и песнях часто слышу вариант "ветра":
*Hо есть на свете ветер перемен,

Он прилетит, прогнав ветра измен,

Развеет он, когда придёт пора

Ветра разлук, обид ветра.*

Или это, кажется, Высоцкого:
*Мы говорим не «штормы», а «шторма» -

Слова выходят коротки и смачны.

Ветра не ветры сводят нас с ума

Из палуб выкорчевывая мачты.*

Как же все-таки правильно?

Answer (score 2):

Моряки говорят "ветрА", как автомобилисты говорят исключительно "искрА" (не "Искра"), а бухгалтеры "квАртал" (не "квартАл"). Профессиональный сленг.

Comment: Из "профессионального" сленга: "В этом году было очень мало снега, дули ветра, а почва перепылена и нет почти лесополос (Владимир Чивилихин).  "Слышишь, тревожные дуют ветра. Нам расставаться настала пора (Константин Ваншенкин). "Здесь, при слиянии двух рек, Волги и Которости, почти постоянно дуют ветра самые отчаянные и очень охлаждают воздух (И.С. Аксаков. Письма к родным (1849-1856).

Comment: И что? Профессиональный сленг разрешено использовать только профессионалам?

Comment: Думаю, что эти авторы даже и не подозревали, что они пользуются профессиональным сленгом.

Comment: Я, когда захожу в бухгалтерию, сразу начинаю говорить "квАртал" - иначе они не понимают.

Answer (score 1):

В косвенных падежах мн. числа существительное имеет варианты: вЕтров и ветрОв, вЕтрами и ветрАми.

Но в И.п. мн.числа -  только "вЕтры" в нейтральном стиле, а "ветрА" - исключительно поэтический стиль.

КОММЕНТАРИЙ

Ветер, как и многие сущ. м.р., имеет в форме мн.числа И.п. основное окончание Ы и вариантное окончание А/Я, причем окончание А/Я чаще используется в разговорной речи (вексели/векселя, кители/кителя, тракторы/трактора, редакторы/редактора). Возможно, разговорное "ветра"  лучше передает силу свободной стихии и поэтому так любимо поэтами.

Answer (score 0):

Замена безударных "-ы/-и" на ударные "-А/-Я" - жаргонизм, используемый в "экспрессивных" выражениях. С происхождением поверю Высоцкому. Наиболее часто подобная замена используется с морскими терминами.

Comment: А доктора, профессора, директора?

Comment: Всё перечисленное настолько "молодо", что до сих пор считается "ненормативным" (в отличие от "ветрОв", штормОв" и прочих "стакселЕй")